# Conditionally use next.js app or create react app with the same website domain according to users login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, get, create-react-app

I have a website which I've built with CRA, node.js and I want to use ISR for most of the pages.
The problem is that about 20% of the users are registered users, which get their own content, and different header, which means I can only use SSR, and not ISR.

My thought is to use something like:

1. In my  node.js server I would check if the user is logged
2. If he is not logged, I would send a get request to the next.js server, get the static html file and serve it.
3. If the user is logged I would just send him my CRA app.

Another option that I thought about is to use a [proxy server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) with filter on the request which check if the session ID or cookie ID is set

Is it possible? Which option is better?

Shall I be able to use CDN to serve those static files?

Is there any better idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Why you want to redirect logged users to the CRA app? I suppose the CRA is client side only. You can use nextjs without set the getServerSideProps and getstaticprops, you will obtain the same client app as a CRA application

Comment: @dna, exactly you right, I guess Eran was fallen in over-thinking, its simple. we have a Backend and a Frontend. the Frontend is running on Next.JS, awesome, in both server and client we can understand the user is logged-in or not. then route it to the right point. some pages like product page needs to be server-side rendered because of SEO and etc. some page really doesn't need like home, feed and etc.

Comment: @dna I want to use SSG for none logged users. I know I can use SSR for the whole website, but it's important for me that none logged users will get the fastest response.

Comment: @EranShmuel, Have you considered using NextJS middleware to serve the correct content (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware). There are some examples here (https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way you could separate some amount of the pages between logged in and logged out users? That way you can serve at least some of the static content from a CDN.

Comment: @Andrew Hulterstrom
no its the same pages, with the same url. is there any way to use SSG for the not logged users and SSR for the logged users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using next.js I ended up creating my own ISR for my website. This way I could use SSR for registered users and ISR for unregistered users. While using SSR in CRA app is not recommended by the create react app team, I found out that it is pretty simple with the help of [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/a-hands-on-guide-for-a-server-side-rendering-react-app-dd1efa3ec0d8) for SSR, [this article](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/guides/ssr) for SSR with react router. I used react 18 and react router 5.

While this solution worked for me, it is not guaranteed that it will work later so I won't recommend it until the create react app team will recommend it.

The pros of the solution:

1. More freedom with the code. For example, I could serve different pages for mobile and desktop (and still serve static pages).
2. Reduced costs compared to next.js

The cons of the solution

1. Unstable because the create react team doesn't recommend it
2. Missing out of some of the next.js features like images optimization
3. The html pages are not served from CDN (I used [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/))

Answer (score 0):

Just keep everything in the Nextjs application.

If you need static generated pages use `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` or nothing (to have the same result as a CRA app) in that page.

If you need some server related logic use `getServerSideProps` in that page.

---

**UPDATE**
After run `next build`

[image]

The page `test` is a simple component

```
const Test = () => <div>test</div>;

export default Test;
```

In the other pages (`/gpp`, `/gpp/[id]`) `getServerSideProps`  is defined

```
.....
const GppPage: NextPage = () => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title>GPP</title>
    </Head>
    <Box>
      
       ....
    </Box>
  </>
);


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: "mysession"
    }
  };
}

export default GppPage;
```

In the image the Test page is clearly a static page (look at symbols)

If you define in `_app.tsx` some `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` in that case you will inherit the SSR behaviour

Comment: This way I will have to use SSR for the whole website, because logged users get personalization for all pages (different header and few minor details). I want to use SSG for users which are not logged, which are 90% of the users.

Comment: This is not correct. Try to create 2 page one with the component of the page and `getServerSideProps` , the second one just with the exported component of the page. If you build it you will see that the second one is not generated using SSR. I just update the answer with a demostrantion build

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If I'm using next for logged users, its mean to use getServerSideProps at every page(or getInitialProps at the app level) because every user get a different header, and some of the content is different also. this are not different pages, they are the same pages, but some of the details are different for the logged users.

Comment: Logged user has different information, if you use Server Side rendering you can directly inject the user information in some server way. If you use Client Side rendering u need to obtain the user information in some other way. I just suggest to use nextjs for  server side or client side. Use some switch mechanims (or proxy, or whatever) to redirerect logged user to a CRA app has no sense.